# PHP: Get next/prev element of an array with loop if last/first

Tags: php, arrays, navigation

I don't manage to add a navigation arrow to my portfolio. I would like to get next and prev id based on current id. The issue is when the `$current_id` is the last of array, I don't know how to go to the first one to create a kind of loop. And the same if the `$current_id` is the first element, how to have the last element as prev ? I'm stuck, can you please help me ?

Here is my code:

```
<?php 

    $current_id = "10";

    $array = array(
        "1" => "aa",
        "2" => "bb",
        "3" => "cc",
        "4" => "dd",
        "5" => "ee",
        "6" => "ff",
        "7" => "gg",
        "8" => "hh",
        "9" => "ii",
        "10" => "jj",
    );


    $current_index = array_search($current_id, $array);

    $next = $current_index + 1;
    $prev = $current_index - 1;

?>
```

Comment: Are you sure that your key for array will be remain same like 1,2,3...

Comment: Isn't it possible to simply do $array[$current_index + 1]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use modulo `%` for that for the next value:

```
$number_of_elements = count($array);
$next = ($current_index + 1) % $number_of_elements;
```

And an if for the prev value, since modulo does not like negative numbers

```
$prev = $current_index - 1
if ($prev < 0){
    $prev = $number_of_elements - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use modulo THIS way:

```
$current_id = 9;

$array = array(
    "aa",
    "bb",
    "cc",
    "dd",
    "ee",
    "ff",
    "gg",
    "hh",
    "ii",
     "jj",
);

$next = ($current_id+($count=count($array))+1)%$count;
$previous = ($current_id+$count-1)%$count;

print("$previous $next");
```

Comment: @BasvanStein: It is way more elegant than your solution and the efficiency difference must be close to 1/infinite. Anyway, check it now, you'll find it hyper-efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reset()` and `end()` functions to move the array pointer to the beginning and the end of the array. So, before processing your array you could do something like:

```
end($array);
$end = key($array);
```

and then:

```
reset ($array);
while (current ($array)) {
    $current_index = key($array);
    $current_value = current($array);
    if ($current_index == $end) 
        reset($array);
    else
        next($array);
}
```

Or, build some sort of linked list where every element of your array would have a pointer/reference to the next element.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve it , if you have last id of page .

Try something as

```
$last=count($array);
$next = $current_index + 1;
$next=$next<0?$last:$next;
$prev = $current_index - 1;
$prev =$prev==$last?1:$prev
```